# Is it possible to associate TFS work items when using git-tf

Tags: git, tfs, git-tf

I am using git-tf and am finding that after checking in my changes to TFS I end up having to  manually associating these changes with TFS work items. I see the `--work-item` option in the documentation but am wondering if it is possible to have these associations made automatically; perhaps using some tag in the comment such as `#refs 17`. I have found answers using git-tfs but am wondering if this is possible without changing tools; I prefer the cross platform support of git-tf.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there are a number of ways to associate work items with commits.  As you note, you can use a checkin argument like `--associate` or `--resolve` checkin options to associate or resolve a workitem, respectively.

If you prefer to use a comment to drive this system, you can use the "mentions" features that are in git-tf 2.0.2, similar to the "mentions" features in the Team Foundation Service git integration.  In that case, simply add `#1234` to the comment of your git commit in order to associate with work item `1234`, then checkin using `git tf checkin --mentions`.

Comment: That does sound like the functionality I am looking for, however it does not appear to work and I see no reference to the option in the documentation. I am running version 2.0.2.20130214. 

Edit:
To clarify: I get an error stating that the option is unknown

Comment: @davidk: thanks for the update - you're right, 2.0.2 does not have mentions support, you would have to build from source for that functionality.  Let me see if we can't get a new version built soon.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea when a new build might be released?